# Update wp-config.php and lost pages

Tags: wp-config

I recently made a small change to my `wp-config.php` by adding a memory limit line on a local version that didn't have the correct db settings. When I uploaded it, the db connection obviously broke. After I corrected the db settings and re-uploaded the `wp-config.php`, I was greeted with the installation page.

Now all my links are broken, even after refreshing the permalinks. However, all the data is still in my db. How do I reconnect all my pages to the db so that I don't loose any settings?

Comment: If the database information is correct, things should work. Something has happened that you haven't explained.

Comment: This was the line I added: 
`/** Increase PHP Memory Limit. */
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );`

Comment: That line should not have caused the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was the db table prefix.  My local config file had the wrong table prefix and once that was changed, everything was where it should be.